# Subshell in script wont print corectly

Tags: bash, scripts, sh

Why does my shell and subshell only print the first hour in my for loop? It's supposed to loop through all 24 hours in a day but only prints the first hour correctly.

---

```
{
for D in $(seq -f "%02g" 1 9); do

File=($(find -name "PaloAlto_traffic_$M-$D-$Y.zip"))
unzip -j $File
Filetmp=($(find -name "traffic_$M-$D-$Y.total"))

D=$(echo $D | sed -e 's/^0*//')

for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 0 23); do

echo $i 

    grep -F -s "$month  $D $i:" $Filetmp > TempOutput1.txt

    countAllow=($(grep -F -c 'allow' TempOutput1.txt))
    countDeny=($(grep -F -c 'deny' TempOutput1.txt))
    #Add new 'variable=($(grep)) statement here'

    echo -e "$M/0$D/$Y $i:00,$countAllow,$countDeny" >> AD-Results-$month-$Y
    echo "$((10#$i+1))/24       hours completed for $month $D" 
    rm -f $Filetmp
done
done
} & #Subshell 2A
{ 
for D in $(seq -f "%02g" 10 18); do

File=($(find -name "PaloAlto_traffic_$M-$D-$Y.zip"))
unzip -j $File
Filetmp=($(find -name "traffic_$M-$D-$Y.total"))

for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 0 23); do

    grep -F -s "$month $D $i:" $Filetmp > TempOutput2.txt

    countAllow=($(grep -F -c 'allow' TempOutput2.txt))
    countDeny=($(grep -F -c 'deny' TempOutput2.txt))
    #Add new 'variable=($(grep)) statement here'

    echo -e "$M/$D/$Y $i:00,$countAllow,$countDeny" >> AD-Results-$month-$Y
    echo "$((10#$i+1))/24       hours completed for $month $D" 
    rm -f $Filetmp
done
done
}
wait
```

---

Sample output data: (Date Time , Allow , Deny)

```
05/10/2014 00:00,3242,6758
05/10/2014 01:00,0,0 #This should be the same as above line but outputs 0,0
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably remove the file named by `$Filetmp` too soon. The `rm` command is inside the inner loop:

```
        rm -f $Filetmp
    done
done
```

Due to this, the file is removed after the first iteration through the inner loop (i.e. when $i = 0). Subsequent iterations ($i > 0) will not find the file. No error is reported because you call grep with option `-s`, but the resulting counts are obviously zero.

The `rm` command should be outside the inner loop:

```
    done
    rm -f $Filetmp
done
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. That's what I get for programming 9 hours a day. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Roboman1723 If it functions accept his answer he will have is points and we will see close your problem. :-)